# Not receiving Square Connect Webhook for INVENTORY_UPDATED events

Tags: webhooks, square, square-connect

I have followed the instructions for setting up Square Connect web hooks.

I entered my Notification URL in the developer portal and enabled web hooks. I then sent a test notification. I verified that is working correctly.

I subscribed to `"INVENTORY_UPDATED"` with the `Update Webhooks` endpoint.

I verified that worked by calling `/v1/{{location_id}}/webhooks`. The response is

```
["INVENTORY_UPDATED"]
```

So I know that my location is properly subscribed to `INVENTORY_UPDATED` notifications.

But when I sign into the dashboard and create new items or update the inventory 
count on those items, I don't receive any notifications.

I'm stumped.

Do inventory updates in the dashboard trigger `INVENTORY_UPDATED` webhook events? If so, did I miss a step?

Any suggestions of how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you use slack? It might be easier to do some back and forth trouble shooting there. You can get an invite at [squ.re/slack](http://squ.re/slack)

Comment: After working with the Square team, the answer is that there are issues with the web hook infrastructure and the workaround is to poll for changes. webhook delivery is not guaranteed so we planned on doing that anyways to fill in gaps, but being forced constantly watch for all changes was not acceptable to us. So we switched to Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the webhook notification by:

1. open your terminal or cmd (on your PC).
2. Run (curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[\"INVENTORY_UPDATED\"]" https://connect.squareup.com/v1/YOUR_LOCATION_ID/webhooks)

NOTE: Your Access token and Location are found on the dashboard of your square account.